# Is Stack Overflow the right site for asking about debugging tools/techniques?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask for information about tools and techniques to investigate and solve performance and logic errors in JavaEE applications but I am not sure if it falls on the "don't ask for software recommendations" rule or any similar for Stack Overflow or if there is already a Stack Exchange site for this kind of questions.

Can you tell me if SO or another Stack Exchange site is the right one for these questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way to go is just focus on *technique*, and let the tools fall where they may. Describe the bottlenecks and errors (or the symptoms of them) that you're getting, what makes them particularly difficult to scope and what you more or less *expect* to find if you could, but can't effectively pinpoint.

Then, ask, how can you confirm your suspicions, reiterating that these types of things can be extremely tedious to scope.

The solution is probably going to be a combination of tools, possibly some advanced sleuthing while using them. You don't need to come right out and ask for debuggers that can handle it.

As an aside, I do realize that this is *essentially* the same question just worded differently, but you're doing a much better job of narrowing down the types of answers you'd receive.

There are some cases where all you can really do *is* just come out and say "*I want to accomplish [y]. I know I need something that does [x], I can't find anything, what does [x] so I can produce [y]?*" - I'd like to get to the point on Stack Overflow that we could be a little more lenient with those, but that ... could be quite a while.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right in the sense that I should ask for the technique first and then see what tool can help me perform that debugging technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know what tools you should be using, then you are correct that that is not an appropriate question here as it is asking for a product recommendation.

If you're just asking, in general, for techniques for debugging/investigating problems, then such a question would most certainly be "too broad".  You should be asking *specific* questions on a much narrower scope than that.

Comment: To avoid the "too broad" flag I could try and ask the specific technique required for my particular need, though I could fall into the "too narrow" flag